# Any app to locate or spy my lost iPhone device (didnt activate find mym iphone)

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, icloud

Yesterday my iPhone was stolen but I can not find it in my iCloud account with the Find My iPhone app. Currently I have access to my iCloud account
but I dont see the iPhone in the tracking app. I can see it in another section and registered to my personal account.

Apple says I need to activate iCloud and Find My iPhone configuration before it had been stolen. Why they cant remotelly install or configurate it to track the device?

Is it there any other app in the Apple market which I can remotely install and track my device or spy what they do with it? Any app which doesnt need any type of configuration once installed, since I see there are a lot but most of them require to be installed before it has been stolen.

Thanks.

Comment: In principle, the [gaps in the SS7 protocol](https://media.ccc.de/browse/congress/2014/31c3_-_6249_-_en_-_saal_1_-_201412271715_-_ss7_locate_track_manipulate_-_tobias_engel.html#video) allow "anyone" to track (and manipulate) any mobile phone by just knowing the phone number (I suppose the SIM has been replaced by now, but the trick should also work by IMEI)

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, but your our of luck. Unless your phone was jailbroken and you had an app that allowed for what your explaining, theres no way to can instal and app on your device remotely, not to mention that you WILL need setup when you install an app like that.